# Signup email link doesn't work when your name is... unusual

Tags: bug, status-declined, unicode, sign-up

I tried to register an account with the name ௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵௵.

However, doing so generated an email verification with a link that 404s, making it impossible to finish the sign-up process.

Comment: Why, just why??

Comment: What link did it generate?

Comment: @StephenLeppik A long one with what I assume are the usual parameters (email, auth token, return page, etc), but also including the long name, unescaped.

Comment: @bluefeet Eh... For science!

Comment: There's a *The Fifth Element* joke here somewhere...

Comment: If it worked, I'd like to suggest this as the avatar: http://www.be2hand.com/upload/201206/201206-16-190239_S9-4.jpg

Comment: Orlp - is this a strange type of "security test"? Remember that in some jurisdictions it already would count as "hacking" so be aware...

Comment: heh. I'm a *native* LITERATE tamil speaker and I had to go ask my dad what the heck that symbol was. Its pretty obscure and you'd only find it in an astrological almanac

Comment: The link will work, just not until next year.